# Why /var/lib/cni/networks is null after creating a kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cni

Installed a kubernetes cluster with Calico, CoreDNS.

Check one CoreDNS's event message got

```
Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

Under `/var/lib/cni/networks/` directory there is nothing. Why? How to fix?

Even all the pods' status is Running, but worrying about its healthy.

logs

```
# kubectl logs coredns-1308140hfw -n kube-system
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
.:53
[INFO] plugin/reload: Running configuration MD5 = 20328084ha6966e76816bcd928foa
CoreDNS-1.7.0
linux/amd64, go1.14.4, f59c03d
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
[INFO] plugin/ready: Still waiting on: "kubernetes"
I0804 08:18:03.874045       1 trace.go:116] Trace[336122540]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2020-08-04 08:17:33.872753993 +0000 UTC m=+0.038838328) (total time: 30.001059939s):
Trace[336122540]: [30.001059939s] [30.001059939s] END
E0804 08:18:03.874108       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: Get "https://[IPv6]:443/api/v1/endpoints?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp [IPv6]:443: i/o timeout
I0804 08:18:03.874047       1 trace.go:116] Trace[208240456]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2020-08-04 08:17:33.872755558 +0000 UTC m=+0.038839930) (total time: 30.001213767s):
Trace[208240456]: [30.001213767s] [30.001213767s] END
E0804 08:18:03.874137       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Namespace: Get "https://[IPv6]:443/api/v1/namespaces?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp [IPv6]:443: i/o timeout
I0804 08:18:03.874214       1 trace.go:116] Trace[1106410694]: "Reflector ListAndWatch" name:pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125 (started: 2020-08-04 08:17:33.872753715 +0000 UTC m=+0.038838086) (total time: 30.001438405s):
Trace[1106410694]: [30.001438405s] [30.001438405s] END
E0804 08:18:03.874248       1 reflector.go:178] pkg/mod/k8s.io/client-go@v0.18.3/tools/cache/reflector.go:125: Failed to list *v1.Service: Get "https://[IPv6]:443/api/v1/services?limit=500&resourceVersion=0": dial tcp [IPv6]:443: i/o timeout
```

Comment: Can you update your question with coredns pod logs?

Comment: @acid_fuji I added logs.

Comment: This readiness probe failed just once or is it failing constantly?

Comment: @acid_fuji I think once only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How readiness probe works?

> Sometimes, applications are temporarily unable to serve traffic. For
> example, an application might need to load large data or configuration
> files during startup. In such cases, you don't want to kill the
> application, but you don’t want to send it requests either. Kubernetes
> provides readiness probes to detect and mitigate these situations. A
> pod with containers reporting that they are not ready does not receive
> traffic through Kubernetes Services.

When a pod is started, Kubernetes can be configured to wait for a configurable amount of time to pass before performing the first readiness check. After that, it invokes the probe periodically and acts based on the result of the readiness probe. If a pod reports that it’s not ready, it’s removed from the service. If the pod then becomes ready again, it’s re-added.

This means that in your situation your `coreDNS` pod was not entirely running but Kubernetes already started sending probes to check it's `readiness`.

Thanks to those probes, when you have a couple of replicas, Kubernetes will direct traffic only to those which are healthy (with a successful probe).

PS. My `/var/lib/cni/networks/`  directory is also empty.